# Regex allowing and disallowing characters

Tags: regex

I'm working on a regex string to validate page numbers as numbers only. The regex string i'm using is `^products/([^/]+)/page-([^/]+[0-9]+)/sort-([^/]+)/?$` and the url being used in the example is `products/mens/page-1/sort-newest-first`, that string fails with the regex match.. however a 2 digit number works - such as `products/mens/page-10/sort-newest-first`.

Anybody know why it disallows one digit within the rule yet 2 digits or greater are valid? I'm stumped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 ^products/([^/]+)/page-([^/]+[0-9]+)/sort-([^/]+)/?$
                         ^^^^^
```

This says, "Match a character other than `/` between the `-` and at least one number followed by `/`." So, if you have `...page-1/`, there's only one character total for `[^/]+[0-9]+` to match, which fails. Just remove the `[^/]+` here:

```
 ^products/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)/sort-([^/]+)/?$
```

Comment: All the answers provided are good and detailed answers, but this provides the best solution. Cheers Ed, do you think [0-9]+ or \d is better though? Debating which to use..

Comment: Glad to help! `[0-9]` and `\d` are the same, so it's a matter of preference. Many would say that `\d` is better because it is "purer" and because `[0-9]` adds clutter. Others find that `\d` reduces readability slightly. In practical terms, it really doesn't matter, so pick whatever is easiest for you to understand and maintain.

Comment: Alright cheers, i'll stick with [0-9] as that to me is more readable. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `[^/]+` that comes after the `page-`. the reason is this says to look for at least one character that is not a `/` followed by at least one digit.

So in the example of having one digit it would be consumed by the `[^/]` but since there is not at least one digit following it your regex will fail. However, two digits or more would work because the first would get consumed the same way but have at least one digit following it.

Comment: Ahhhh, i see! Cheers.. that makes sense. Still new to regex and trying to edit the code where wildcards were used. They are all good until you want specific handling of characters and what not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `[^/]+` after `page`. Change it to `[^/0-9]*`:

```
^products/([^/]+)/page-([^/0-9]*[0-9]+)/sort-([^/]+)/?$
```

`[^/]+`, which is "1 or more", is consuming the first digit of the number when it immediately follows `"page-"`.

If you make it "zero or more" (to allow for no extra text there) and also negate digits, you'll then capture the page number with `[0-9]+`